# How to delete an item from combobox during runtime after deleting from the database

Tags: mysql, vbscript

```
Private Sub btn_remove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_remove.Click
        Dim Query As String
        Dim query1 As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim strValueYouWant As String = String.Empty
        strValueYouWant = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure,you want delete the selected row?", _
        "Important Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result1 = DialogResult.Yes Then

            mysqlconn.Open()
            Query = "delete from table1 where show_id= '" & strValueYouWant & "'"
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
            Dim k As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Query = Nothing

            cmd.Dispose()

            query1 = "select * from table1"
            Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(query1, mysqlconn)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
            Dim table As New DataTable()
            table.Load(reader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = table

            query1 = Nothing

        ElseIf result1 = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        mysqlconn.Close()
    End Sub
```

I above code I select an item from combobox and create a table using datatable and display it in datagrid. Then I click on remove button. The item is getting deleted from the database but here I want delete that item from combobox as well during run time. I am already using two queries in above code one for selecting and one for deleting if I user loading method it does not work because connection is already open error comes.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this site
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss.aspx

You can use function `RemoveItem`

`YourCombo.RemoveItem(index)`

or clear the combo with `YourCombo.Clear()` and load it again